# Magento2 CSS IE hacks

Tags: magento2, css

In Magento2, want to add css, specifically for IE 8, using

```
 <css src="css/ie-8.css" />
```

Not able to find anywhere in native source code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Then you can use following code:

```
<head>
    <css src="css/ie-8.css" ie_condition="IE 8" />
</head>
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: Good.. let me check

Comment: Worked like a charm!!

Comment: How can we remove a CSS file from all IE broesers?

Comment: Try with `ie_condition=!IE'`

Comment: In what file do we need to add this code?

Comment: @BartłomiejSzubert, This didn't work for me, even in IE also its not loading..
I added like below, <css src="css/ie_styles.css" ie_condition="IE" />

Comment: @BartłomiejSzubert, css file is not loading instead it shows as commented..

Comment: @jafarpinjar this is how it works for IE, such scripts are wrapped in comments with condition, and if this condition results in true then browser loads such file

Comment: @BartłomiejSzubert, I need to load the file in IE 11, so i given <css src="css/ie-8.css" ie_condition="IE 11" /> which is not loading where <css src="css/ie-8.css" ie_condition="IE 9" /> is working fine

Comment: @jafarpinjar it seems that such hack is implemented only in IE up to 9. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541306/how-to-write-a-css-hack-for-ie-11 - this doesn't seem to be issue with solution added here but limitation in IE11 itself

Comment: @BartłomiejSzubert, okay that's fine